# ImGui, GLFW: ImGui Window is not showing up when it's over GLFW Window

Tags: c++, glfw, imgui

I set up glfw, then I added ImGui. Both of them are working, but when I try to put an ImGui Window over a GLFW Window, the ImGui window disappear. I tried to create a Dockspace and the result was the same. I never encountered something like this

My project is big so I left here only the part where is ImGui initialized and the main loop.

Any idea?

```
void App::Run()
{
    IMGUI_CHECKVERSION();
    ImGui::CreateContext();
    ImGuiIO& io = ImGui::GetIO(); (void)io;
    //io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_NavEnableKeyboard;       // Enable Keyboard Controls
    //io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_NavEnableGamepad;      // Enable Gamepad Controls
    io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_DockingEnable;           // Enable Docking
    io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_ViewportsEnable;         // Enable Multi-Viewport / Platform Windows
    //io.ConfigViewportsNoAutoMerge = true;
    //io.ConfigViewportsNoTaskBarIcon = true;

    // Setup Platform/Renderer backends
    ImGui_ImplGlfw_InitForOpenGL((GLFWwindow*)(m_Window->Get()), true);
    ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Init();

    // Setup Dear ImGui style
    ImGui::StyleColorsDark();
    //ImGui::StyleColorsClassic();

    // When viewports are enabled we tweak WindowRounding/WindowBg so platform windows can look identical to regular ones.
    ImGuiStyle& style = ImGui::GetStyle();
    if (io.ConfigFlags & ImGuiConfigFlags_ViewportsEnable)
    {
        style.WindowRounding = 0.0f;
        style.Colors[ImGuiCol_WindowBg].w = 1.0f;
    }

    while (m_Running)
    {
        for (auto layer : m_LayerStack)
            layer->OnUpdate();

        while (!m_EventQueue.empty())
        {
            for (auto layer : m_LayerStack)
                layer->OnEvent(*m_EventQueue.front());

            CORE_PRINT(m_EventQueue.front()->ToString());
            delete m_EventQueue.front();
            m_EventQueue.pop();
        }

        ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_NewFrame();
        ImGui_ImplGlfw_NewFrame();
        ImGui::NewFrame();

        ImGui::SetNextWindowPos(ImVec2(m_Window->GetPosX(), m_Window->GetPosY()));
        ImGui::SetNextWindowSize(ImVec2(m_Window->GetWidth(), m_Window->GetHeight()));
        ImGui::Begin("DockSpace", NULL,
            ImGuiWindowFlags_NoTitleBar |
            ImGuiWindowFlags_NoResize |
            ImGuiWindowFlags_NoMove |
            ImGuiWindowFlags_NoScrollbar |
            ImGuiWindowFlags_NoScrollWithMouse
        );
        // Declare Central dockspace
        auto dockspaceID = ImGui::GetID("HUB_DockSpace");
        ImGui::DockSpace(dockspaceID, ImVec2(0.0f, 0.0f), ImGuiDockNodeFlags_None | ImGuiDockNodeFlags_PassthruCentralNode/*|ImGuiDockNodeFlags_NoResize*/);
        ImGui::End();

        ImGui::ShowDemoWindow();

        ImGui::Begin("Example");
        ImGui::Button("Text");
        ImGui::Text("Text");
        ImGui::End();

        ImGuiIO& io = ImGui::GetIO();
        io.DisplaySize = ImVec2(m_Window->GetWidth(), m_Window->GetHeight());

        // Render dear imgui into screen
        ImGui::Render();
        ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData());

        if (io.ConfigFlags & ImGuiConfigFlags_ViewportsEnable)
        {
            GLFWwindow* backup_current_context = glfwGetCurrentContext();
            ImGui::UpdatePlatformWindows();
            ImGui::RenderPlatformWindowsDefault();
            glfwMakeContextCurrent(backup_current_context);
        }

        m_Window->Update();
    }

    // Cleanup
    ImGui_ImplOpenGL3_Shutdown();
    ImGui_ImplGlfw_Shutdown();
    ImGui::DestroyContext();

}
```

'''